# How to send each client ID data from Database to each different email

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql

I m struggling to send Each ClientID Information from Database to their specific Email Address.

My training exercise was to use this SQL (*See Below*) that have 3 different tables that are as follow: Client, Sites, Job_Cards. 
Now I have create a SQL that gives me the output that I need. But my problem is based at the fact that 1 clientID may have one or Many SiteID. one SiteID may have one and many Job_Card#.
When I create my PHP Script the Data Displays as follow:  [Link](http://kopanang.co.za/monthreport.php)  on a HTML page.

My Question is in 2 Parts:

1. How can I format the table to Display ONLY 1 ClientID or ClientName with the list of Job#, site name and Description of this single Client?
2. How may I send an Email to Each of the ClientName Without Duplicate ID. And What php script will be good to use to send Emails to Each Clients?

Here is my PHP Script and My SQL Statment:

```
$sqlSelect = "SELECT DISTINCT(cl.client_id),
             client_name,
             DATE(jb.date),
             jb.job_number,
             jb.repair,
             st.site_name
             FROM
             job_cards jb
             INNER JOIN
             clients cl ON (cl.client_id = jb.client_id)
             LEFT JOIN
             sites st on (st.site_id = jb.site_id)
             WHERE
             jb.completed =  1 
             AND cl.client_id = jb.client_id
             AND jb.date >= DATE_ADD(DATE(NOW()), INTERVAL - 30 DAY)
             ORDER BY cl.client_name ASC";
              //echo $sqlSelect;
              $tresult = mysql_query($sqlSelect);
              //die("ss");
              //$dataCount = mysql_num_rows($result);

               while($userData = mysql_fetch_assoc($tresult)){
                                    if($i%2==0)
                                        $classname = 'evenRow';
                                    else if($i%2==1)

                                //extract($userData);
                                ?>
                            </table>
                        </td>
                </tr>
                <tr> 
                <td align='center' height="30" style="font-size:14px;">
                               <b><?php echo $userData['client_name'];?></b>
                      </td>
                      <td align='center'></td>

                        <td>
                            <table width='100%' cellpadding= '1' border='0'>

                        <thead>
                            <tr>

                            <td style="font-size:13px; text-align:Left;"><b>Date</b></td>
                            <td style="font-size:13px; text-align:Left;"><b>Job #</b></td>
                            <td style="font-size:13px; text-align:left;"><b>Site name</b></td>
                            <td style="font-size:13px; text-align:left;"><b>Description</b></td>
                            </tr>
                            </thead>

                                        <tr class='<?php if(isset($classname)) echo $classname;?>'>



                                    <tr>
                                    <td>
    <?php echo mysql_real_escape_string ($userData['DATE(jb.date)']); ?>
    </td>
    <td>
     <?php echo mysql_real_escape_string($userData['job_number']);?>
    </td>
    <td>
     <?php echo mysql_real_escape_string($userData['site_name']);?>
    </td>
    <td>
     <?php echo mysql_real_escape_string($userData['repair']);?>
    </td>
                     </tr>                        
                                        <?php $i++;
                                }
                                    ?>         
                                        </tr>

                           </table>
                            <table width='100%' cellpadding= '1' border='1'>
                                        <tr>
                                        </tr>
                            </table>
```

**Please May Some 1 Help me. I tried What I could But Still I cannot send emails and the Table format doesn't display the way I want.
Thank.**

Comment: Could you provide your database schema, please?

Comment: My Database schema is as follow Tables: Clients: client_id, customer#, client_name, address, rep_#... Job_Cards: Job_#, Site_ID, Machine_id, client_id, desc, rep_id, completed, date,...   Sites: site_id, client_id, machine_id, site_ref, site_name, rep_id, ...

Comment: @Wisdm, That is my database Schema.

Comment: Okay, and where is email id?

Comment: @wisdm, in the client table there is NO Email id! That is where I'm struggling. And is going to be various user define Emails. Also my main focus is how would I send Emails to each ClientID at the same time?